# Perplexing Complexity - Tricky Table Join

Tags: sql-server, database-design, join, normalization

I've been struggling with this specific set of tables for some time. There are three tables (used to be two, but it was necessary to add a third). The tables are `Request`, `PartInfo`, and `Status`. `Request` is used by the customer via a form that enters data into the table. `Status` is for our service agents to keep track of progress on customer requests. `PartInfo` is the new table, containing common data accessed by both parties.

The trick is that with each request, there is a running log of changes to that request which are stored in the same table, and linked to the original request in that series via a self-joining key called `FirstRequestID` (which I'll abbreviate as `FID`). The same is true for the `Status` table. Here is my basic table structure as I have currently designed it (*Note: It's not too late to change the architecture if there is a better approach*):

```
Request          PartInfo          Status
-------          --------          ------
ID               ID                ID
FID              FID               FID
PartInfoID       PartNum           PartInfoID
ProductID        Revision          StatusID
CategoryID       Description       Comments
```

Now say I want to display the information on a particular request (including part info and status changes) in a ASP.NET GridView table. The "particular request" is identified by the `FID`.

**Question**:
How can I ensure that when I'm looking at either the Request history or the Status history, it's always pulling the proper information from the PartInfo (shared) table? In other words, what's the best way to link these three tables with the proper relationship without having 50 different junction tables to account for all the exceptions?

Comment: As a note, `Request` & `Status` are Master tables, and `` is a Details table shared by both of the others. Furthermore, `CategoryID` refers to the type of request, not product, but this is immaterial as the real struggle lies in defining the relationship between these three tables and their shared data. I suppose I could just have the fields from `PartInfo` copied in both of the other tables, but this would be even further from proper normalization right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, but my first take on this schema was “this is a mess”. This data needs to be normalized. Unfortunately, there’s not enough information here to determine how to best do so. Based on your descriptions and part names, I come up with the following ideas.

- The main entity is the Request.
- Reqeusts contain Products
- Requests contain Categories (unless the Category is an attribute of a Product)
- Products contain Parts (unless it’s Categories that contain Parts)
- The implication is that a Requested Product is associated with an arbitrary number of Parts (as opposed to a standardized set of Parts for that Product).
- Status is used to track change in state of a Request over time (and is not completely dependant upon Products, Categories, or Parts)

This suggests the following tables

```
REQUESTS
RequestId
DateTimeCreated

PRODUCTS
ProductId
--  Add CategoryId, if it’s a Product attribute

CATEGORIES
CategoryId

REQUESTPRODUCTS
RequestProductId
RequestId
ProductId
DateTimeAdded
--  Add StatusId if a status entry must be made every time a product is requested
--  Note extra surrogate key. ReqeustId + ProductId + DateTimeAdded should be the
--   natural key, unless two identical products can be requested at the same time
--   (in which case add an “Quantity” column)


REQUESTCATEGORIES
RequestId
CategoryId
DateTimeAdded
--  Suorrogate key optional, as it’s not referenced by other tables
--  Drop, if categories are product attributes

PARTS
PartId

REQUESTPRODUCTPARTS
RequestProductId
PartId
--  Add StatusId if a status entry must be made every time a part is requested

STATUS
StatusId
RequestId
DateTimeAdded
Comments
```

There’s a log of ways this could go. You may end up with a lot of “junction” tables, but then your data will have referential integrity and accurate SQL queries become much, much simpler to write.

Comment: LMBO, oh my... I actually knew it was a horrible design. I was just trying to come up with a viable and quick solution in my time crunch. I'm going to get away from my desk for a few minutes to re-think this in light of your comments. I suspect I'll replace `FID` in the `PartInfo` table with `RequestID` & `StatusID`, and remove `PartInfoID` from the other tables. This way if the update to the `PartInfo` table originates from `Status`, the `StatusID` field will update while the `RequestID` will remain unchanged. Is this kinda what you're getting at? Thanks :)

Comment: Nope, crap. That doesn't work either because the `RequestID` & `StatusID` keys would not be unique. :( I'm still a novice at DB design, so I often run into these kinds of tricky problems to solve, especially given the extremely complex business solution I have been assigned to develop a solution for. There are so many exceptions to everything in this process that it's very challenging to account for everything. >.<

Comment: That "time crunch" is your biggest enemy. It sounds like you need to step back and re-analyze the system you are modeling, and possibly then revising your database schema (tables et. al.) to describe it better. And, sadly, yes, the more "abstract" or free-form the system, the more complex the database architecture.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty much screwed, lol. About my only option for ideas at this point is to call up my old professor who had 13 years in industry as a DB developer. I'm either going to have to re-architect a lot all these tables or tell my colleagues, "sorry but it can't be done given the current time constraints." >.<

Comment: The phrase "Technical Debt" might come in useful. If something has to be done and done quickly, and for whatever (usually business) reason the time/effort can't be taken to "do it right" up front, it gets done quickly/cheaply, and everyone says "oh, we'll go back and fix it later on". That's technical debt, knowing you took shortcuts and ought to go back and fix it some day. If/when/eventually too much TD piles up, and things crack, break, and ultimately fall down. Drawing analogies to Greece might help here, too.

Comment: Even though this isn't the best answer, that is mostly my fault as I was having such trouble with the problem that I couldn't phrase the question better. I'll give credit because of the effort Philip put in, and he definitely made some valid points as well; and yes, it was a mess :P. Thanks. :)